# how to ad a panel in the properties/data Speaker specific

Tags: panel

I can't find anywhere how can i add the panel of an operator in the Speaker properties data tab only.
it appears in all other objects data tab and i can't find a context list

[image]

```
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
"""Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
bl_context = "data"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Add a poll method.**

To narrow it down could look to see if context object is of type 'SPEAKER' or since it is in the properties space, there is a `speaker` context member available when the object is not a  speaker it will be none.

```
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "data"

    @classmethod 
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.speaker is not None
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')
```

Comment: I hope this is Python, because I'm a beginner learning it. Thanks for sharing.